# Date with filter in angularJs

Tags: angularjs, date, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

I'm trying to select objects within an `ng-repeat`, using `ng-if= "condition == {{date | date:"M"}}"`

`{{date | date:"M"}}` works in my Angular page, returning "5"; but does not seem to work within my `ng-if`. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Here is the non working code:

```
<li ng-repeat="task in tasks" ng-if="task.month == {{date | date:"M"}} || task.month == 0">
    <a href="#/task/{{task.id}}"><h2>{{task.title}}</h2></a>
</li>
```

And this is a working example, when I replace the `{{date}}` with a "5";

```
<li ng-repeat="task in tasks" ng-if="task.month == 5 || task.month == 0">
    <a href="#/task/{{task.id}}"><h2>{{task.title}}</h2></a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ng-if` expects a Javascript expression, and the `{{ }}` brackets are not valid Javascript.  The brackets can be used in the `href` and other places, as you have shown, but not in the `ng-if`.

Instead, use Javascript's [date.getMonth()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) in your expression:

```
<li ng-repeat="task in tasks" ng-if="task.month == date.getMonth() || task.month == 0">
```

Comment: I still cant make it work. I made a plunkr to show an example:[link](http://plnkr.co/edit/nFsKmWIU5ALk1owAdxSr?p=preview) what i'm i missing? thanks in advance.